# Is “Do your worst” understood to be a cheeky double entendre?

Tags: idioms, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Can be said (good-natured or not) to an opponent before a match in defiance of their abilities.  *“Bring it on”* is a similar phrase.

I just realized it can be a backhanded slight.  *“[I hope you] do your worst.”*

Is that just understood by the general populous and I missed it all along, or is it impossible to know?

Maybe it originated in a Shakespeare play or something and it ***is*** understood to be one or the other.

Comment: I've always taken it to mean "do the worst/nastiest thing you can to me -- I can take it and dish it out right back at you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "do your worst"—or rather "do thy worst"—goes back to the 1500s. It appears twice in [Shakespeare's sonnets](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uw4WAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT52&dq=%22thy+worst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMyOHJ5NXKAhVHzWMKHWH8B90Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22thy%20worst%22&f=false) (published in 1609). At the end of sonnet 19:

> Yet **doe thy worst** ould Time dispight thy wrong,
>
> My loue shall in my verse euer liue young.

And at the beginning of sonnet 92:

> Bvt **doe thy worst** to steale thy selfe away,
>
> For tearme of life thou art assured of mine,
>
> And life no longer then thy loue will stay,
>
> For it depends vpon that loue of thine.

Earlier still, from "[Owen Royden to the curious company of sycophants](https://books.google.com/books?id=4uQ-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PR5&dq=%22thy+worst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCjIXz69XKAhVB32MKHaP0C-s4HhDoAQhKMAk#v=onepage&q=%22thy%20worst%22&f=false)" in *A Glorious Gallery of Gallant Inventions* (1578):

> But in thy hart, there is a burning spark.
>
> And (whiles thou liues) that sicknesse will thee greaue:
>
> But **doo thy worst**, and doo no more but right,
>
> The learned route, wil laughe at thy despight.

And from [*The Interlude of a Contract of Marriage between Wit and Wisdom*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gCJaAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA281&dq=%22brags+and+do+thy+worst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi76paK69XKAhULw2MKHYLtByIQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22brags%20and%20do%20thy%20worst%22&f=false) (1579) in *Five Anonymous Plays*:

> Leave off thy brags, and **do thy worst**;
>
> Thy words may not prevail at first.

Likewise, "[Musica Transalpina](https://books.google.com/books?id=gtQIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PR4&dq=%22thy+worst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCjIXz69XKAhVB32MKHaP0C-s4HhDoAQg3MAU#v=onepage&q=%22thy%20worst%22&f=false)" (1588) includes a madrigal that starts with these words:

> False loue now shoot & spare not, now **doe thy worst** I care not, & to dispatch mee, vse all thyne art & all thy craft to catch mee, and all thy craft to catch mee, for yeeres amisse bestow'd ...

From [*A Pleasaunte Commodie, called Looke About You*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iEY6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PT73&dq=%22thy+worst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs8uaB5tXKAhUB42MKHbOWDF84FBDoAQgqMAM#v=onepage&q=%22thy%20worst%22&f=false) (1600), we have this variant form:

> [Robert of] Glo[ster]. Tut, I am ready, to **thy worst** I dare thee.

My personal favorite, though, is from the very beginning of Ben Jonson, [*The Alchemist*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7vxdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA606&dq=%22thy+worst+I+fart%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj--M7Qy93KAhUU7GMKHSW1BM8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22thy%20worst%20I%20fart%22&f=false) (1616), where the audience is greeted with this hostile exchange between the unreliable house-keeper Face and the ne'er-do-well "alchemist" Subtle:

> *Face:* Believe it I will.
>
> *Subtle:* **Thy worst**. I fart at thee.

Here, "Do thy worst" has been shortened to "Thy worst," with complete assurance that the audience will understand the meaning and supply the missing *do*.

The meaning of "do thy worst" in all of these instances is the same (and also essentially the same as with instances of the modern phrase "do your worse"): It's a challenge issued to the person or thing being spoken to, to give the challenger his (or her or its) best shot, the implication being that the challenger will withstand the blow and then (a) soundly pummel the other into submission; or (b) remain standing, unbowed and unrepentant; or (c) not care, for his heart is broken anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The definition given in dictionaries is the same and  implies a defiant  attitude:.

***[Do your worst](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-your-worst):***

> - used for saying that you are not frightened by something or someone because you are confident that they cannot harm you.
>
>   - *Let them do their worst – I’m not scared.*

(Macmillandictionary)

Ah early usage example is from 1672 in a phrase  by  by George Villiers, the 2nd Duke of Buckingham, in his satirical play The Rehearsal:

> - "Now, Criticks, ***do your worst,*** that here are met; For, like a Rook, I have hedg'd in my Bet."

([The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/hedge-your-bets.html))

Comment: Whoo.  I was afraid all these years people were having a laugh and I never knew.  But you can be sure the next time I play golf with dad, I will tell him to _**do his worst**!_  But now I fret a bit in the other direction.  I'm wondering if it is possible to know if it _has ever_ been confirmed used (in print) as a purposeful double entendre – wishing someone the worst outcome.